# How I can get the queryset created and passed by a view in the serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a review model which has a large data so, first I do some filtration based on the date range and other things, I did it like this:

```
class ProgressView(generics.ListAPIView):
"""
Return a list of all Feedback reviews for progress.
"""
serializer_class = ReviewProgressSerializer
filterset_class = ProgressFilter
pagination_class = UnlimitedPagination

def get_queryset(self):
    return Review.objects.filter(division__pk=self.kwargs['division_pk'])
```

Now, I want to do some calculations based on this filtered queryset in the serializer and return this info along with the serialized data, the problem is, I don't know how to get this queryset in the serializer or should I do it in view.

Please note that I need to do both things, serialize the review data and return the calculations too in the same response.

So, my question is how to access the queryset created by view in serializer or should I do that in another place or what.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you can access your current queryset that being serialized from your serializer by `self.instance`